# Which model should I use?

Tags: core-data, plist, realm

I hope my question isn't out of scope on stackoverflow. Let me explain.

Im developing a travelling app with a lot of static pages. For now I use a mix of xib and some data I store into a plist.

Im not sure the plist is the right tool to store persistent and "already in the app" strings, dictionaries and arrays though.

I have a quick look to realm and coredata but they seems more oriented for dynamic data generated by the users. Am I right? My app is not storing dynamic data, not even prefs or things like that.

It's my first app, the kind you're using to have a panorama of all the possibilities offered by iOS and third parties. That's why I'm asking it here, so please be kind if it's not the right place for it!

Comment: It may or may not be a duplicate of that topic, because my question is focused on data that should already be here when the user launch the app for the first time. In that topic, the user is saving tweets and the question is about writing and reading, when I'm just about reading data. 

But maybe CoreData is perfect for read-only purpose too, that's exactly my question !

Comment: Hi Kenneth, I missed that subtlety in your question.  I'll retract the duplicate flag.  But I think pre-loaded read-only data presents many of the same issues in deciding between plists and CoreData as dynamic data.  The answers to the [question](http://stackoverflow.com/q/4964408/3985749) discuss these.  For info there is also [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/q/1638443/3985749) which specifically considers read-only data.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer boils down to "it's up to you", there are tradeoffs with all the solutions here. I work at Realm, so forgive the bias, but it's a fine tool for readonly data too, since you still have access to type-safe models and queries, in a lightweight & efficient data format. See Realm's docs on [bundling pre-built Realms with an app](https://realm.io/docs/swift/latest/#other-realms) for some details.